# MongoDB Aggregate query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to Java and like to know how to build mongoDB query in java.

```
    db.coll.aggregate(
       { $match : {
        loc: {
            "$ref" : "location", 
            "$id" : ObjectId("4fe69610e7e9fa378c3c802e")
        }
    }},
       { $unwind : "$ActivityList" },
   { $match : {
       'ActivityList.user': {
            "$ref" : "userProfile",
            "$id" : ObjectId("4fdeafe1de26fd298262bb82")
        } 
    }},
    { $group : {
        _id : "$ActivityList.type",
        latest: { $max: '$ActivityList.timestamp' }
    }}
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I think your question is really "How do I use the Mongo aggregation framework from the Java driver?" My answer is lame; Read the Freaking Manual: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+The+Aggregation+Framework+with+The+Java+Driver

Answer (score -1):

There is limitation in aggregate command, pipeline can't operate on values of Binary, Symbol, MinKey, MaxKey, DBRef, Code, CodeWScope. Check [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) for more information.